# Excel 365 co-authoring: how to track changes?

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365, sharing

I would like to see who changed which cells in Excel 365 workbook shared for [co-authoring](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/collaborate-on-excel-workbooks-at-the-same-time-with-co-authoring-7152aa8b-b791-414c-a3bb-3024e46fb104).
Something similar that was available for [shared workbooks](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2017/08/09/track-changes-excel/#highlight-changes) like this:

[image: Shared workbook track changes]

Is that possible somehow?

Answer (score 1):

You can enable Track changes feature in Excel 365, you can Open Excel- go to **File**- **Options**- **Customize Ribbon**- select **All Commands**- Add **Track Changes(Legacy)** to an New Group:
[image]

Comment: But this enables the legacy "shared workbooks" feature. I was wondering if there is another non-legacy way how to do it.

Comment: The documentation confirms what stated by @VojtěchDohnal, in previous comment: [Track changes in a Shared Workbook](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/track-changes-in-a-shared-workbook-22aea671-cac7-4fa3-845d-eeb23725bd15) mention that this method is "an older method of tracking changes using a 'Shared Workbook.' The Shared Workbook feature has many limitations and has been replaced by co-authoring. **Co-authoring doesn't provide the ability to track changes.**"